# How to add fields to activeform with js/jQuery in Yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

Hi I have a user form and I want to add a button so that the user can add more contacts dynamically.

```
<form id="user-form">
<div id='dynamicInput'>
    <div><input type='text' placeholder='name'></div>
    <div><input type='text' placeholder='email'></div>
</div>
<input type='button' id='btnadd' value="add contact">
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

If I wasn't using the Framework I would do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/3t06fL3f/
(this is based on very old code) :)

But using Yii2 I'm not sure how to accomplish this, I'm new to yii2 and frameworks in general.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below:

Write the following code into your view:

```
 $this->registerJs('$("#btnadd").on("click",function(){'
    . '$("#dynamicInput").append(\''
    . Html::tag("div",  Html::textInput("name","",['placeholder'=>"name"]))
    . Html::tag("div",  Html::textInput("email","",['placeholder'=>"email"]))
    . '\');'
    . '})');
```

Please note that you need to have:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
```

at top of your page. Otherwise, you should write `yii\helpers\Html::` instead of `Html::`

Comment: thanks that was almost what I wanted but I can handle the rest :)
if you celebrate, Merry Christmas :)

Comment: How do you deal with model validation rules?

Comment: Example above just injects pure HTML element inside of ActiveForm. However, Active form has also handles validation rules and error messages. How to add those - means how to add dynamically field into ActiveForm so validation rules would apply?