# How to add multiple inputs dynamically on click of button in yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2

How can we add multiple inputs for an attribute of single model dynamically in yii2 form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add fields to activeform with js/jQuery in Yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531993/how-to-add-fields-to-activeform-with-js-jquery-in-yii2)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, then you need to use [active fileds](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html).
Example:

```
<?= Html::activeTextInput($model, 'username') ?>
```